# Embedding model structs with same attribute names in golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

Using `go 1.5`, and `gorm`.

Say I want to make an `events` table that has a `created_by_id` and an `updated_by_id` columns.

I write my models like

```
type By struct {
    ByID sql.NullInt64
    By *User
}

type CreatedBy struct {
    By
}

type UpdatedBy struct {
    By
}

type Event struct {
    CreatedBy
    UpdatedBy
}
```

When I try to save an `event` object, the value for the column `by_id` will try to be saved rather than the values for `created_by_id` and `updated_by_id`.  What do I need to do to make sure the column names of `ByID` attribute are different for `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're embedding both `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` into `Event`, so calls to `Event.By` are ambiguous and not allowed (you'd have to be able to specify `Event.CreatedBy.By` and `Event.UpdatedBy.By` explicitly to disambiguate the two fields).

The solution, most likely, would be to *not embed* the types, but actually create a struct with explicit fields:

```
type Event struct {
    CreatedBy CreatedBy
    UpdatedBy UpdatedBy
}
```

`gorm` should now know how to disambiguate the two columns.

Of course if you're only going to embed `By` into `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` for the purposes of column mapping then you shouldn't need to declare new `struct`s:

```
type By struct {
    ByID sql.NullInt64
    By *User
}

type Event struct {
    CreatedBy By
    UpdatedBy By
}
```